# War with spring configured Camel context will not redeploy on JBoss

Tags: jboss, apache-camel

I have a Camel application deployed on JBoss in a WAR file with a spring configuration for starting the Camel context.

It deploys and runs very nicely on a JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA.

If I want to change values in a property file that my application depends on and touch the war file, it normally redeploys the application. But in some cases it fails.

I get the following in the server.log:

```
2017-07-25 12:05:26.671 INFO  class=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy thread="ServerService Thread Pool -- 74" Starting to graceful shutdown 12 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2017-07-25 12:05:26.725 INFO  class=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy thread="Camel (interfacedb) thread #2 - ShutdownTask" Waiting as there are still 4 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds. Inflights per route: [interfacePersistDirect = 1, route1 = 1, pullFromTransferEntityTable = 1, lastScheduledRun = 1]
...
2017-07-25 12:10:26.691 WARN  class=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy thread="ServerService Thread Pool -- 74" Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2017-07-25 12:10:26.691 WARN  class=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy thread="Camel (interfacedb) thread #2 - ShutdownTask" Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2017-07-25 12:10:26.694 INFO  class=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy thread="ServerService Thread Pool -- 74" Graceful shutdown of 12 routes completed in 300 seconds
```

After this the application will not start again. JBoss reports the following in the myApp.war.failed file in the deployments folder.

```
"WFLYDS0022: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [600 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment."
```

The application normally deploys a lot quicker than 600 seconds. I can touch the war file or delete the .failed file, which normally triggers a redeployment, but JBoss keeps giving me the error above in the .failed file.

The application starts normally if I restart the JBoss VM, but I would like to avoid restarting the other applications running on the JBoss instance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your application does not shutdown graceful succesfully within the 300 seconds. You have inflight exchanges which are not complete and can leave the old deployment in an inconsistent state. This depends on what your application does, and why these messages are "stuck" inflight or dont complete in 5 minutes. You can use Red Hat to ask for support/help on EAP with Camel, eg Fuse is their product for that.

Comment: I just saw the notice, "Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.", in the output above. So you say that it just hasn't shut down the application completely and that is why it is not deploying. Even though it logs "Graceful shutdown of 12 routes completed in 300 seconds"

Comment: Read the logs a bit more, it hit the 300 second timeout and then attempt a forced shutdown of those inflights (its only a best effort) but something can be dangling in there. Thats the danger you always have with a JVM (only 1 process on OS) where you host multiple deployments in the same JVM (not really isolated from each other).